# Sorting names in a text file, writing results to another text file

Tags: python, list, sorting, names

I have a csv file containing a few names that are written in one line seperated by commas but no spaces ex. "maho,baba,fika,anst,koka,root". What i would like to do is to sort these names alphabetically and write them to a new text file so the result becomes like this:
anst
baba
fika
etc.

This is my attempt at it which did not work..

```
names = list()
filename = 'users.csv'
with open (filename) as fin:  
      for line in fin:
            names.append(line.strip())

names.sort()
print(names)

filename = 'names_sorted1.txt'
with open (filename, 'w') as fout:
      for name in names:
            fout.write(name + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this *oneliner*:

```
with open("names.csv") as f, open("new.csv", "w") as fw:
    [fw.write(x+"\n") for x in sorted([x for x in ",".join(f.readlines()).split(",")])]
```

---

**new.csv**

anst
baba
fika
koka
maho
root

---

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/e9ec5c36f8)

Comment: You're very welcome @RobinK. If my answer, or any other answer helped you, make sure you accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to sort `names`, which will only contain *one* string: the entire chunk of comma-separated text. What you need is a way to separate it into a `list` of individual names, which can be done with the `split` method:

```
in_filename = 'users.csv'
with open(in_filename ) as fin:  
    names = sorted(fin.read().strip().split(','))
```

Then, we can use the `join` method to combine the `list` into one long string again, where each element from the `list` is separated from the next by `'\n'`:

```
out_filename = 'names_sorted1.txt'
with open(out_filename , 'w') as fout:
    fout.write('\n'.join(names) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `csv` module like,

```
$ cat names.csv
maho,baba,fika,anst,koka,root

$ cat sort_names.py
import csv

with open('names.csv') as csvfile, open('new.txt', 'w') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
   for row in reader:
       print(row)
       for word in sorted(row):
           f.write("{}\n".format(word))

$ python sort_names.py
$ cat new.txt
anst
baba
fika
koka
maho
root
```